# Bound jQuery range slider to input field

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to bound input field to jQuery slider with range option. I tried the [demo](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#hotelrooms) listed in jQuery's website, changing the select field to input, but it is not working. 
My main idea is to handle search GET requests and whenever user edits the input field that would reflect the slider too. Is this possible? Here is my current code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $( "#adv-slider-price-range" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 100000,
            values: [ 0, 100000 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#advc-amount-price" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " and " + ui.values[ 1 ]);
            }
    });
    $( "#advc-amount-price" ).val( $( "#adv-slider-price-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + " and " + $( "#adv-slider-price-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});

<input type="text" name="priceRange" id="advc-amount-price" />
<div id="adv-slider-price-range"></div>
```

Comment: ofc is possible... just create onchange listener to your input and after change you set new values to slider

Comment: But how how will I detect which values was changed? Can you show me some working example, if yo have? Thanks.

Comment: Well so far good. I have to make onchange listener for my input which is a pain.

Comment: By selector. Make listener is pain? Really? So why you programming? To many examples exist of this.  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_slider.htm

Comment: My point was that input fields require different type of onchange event handling.